# Access Param in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know this is something you can't do inside of rails or aren't supposed to do but I need to somehow get the amount a user is inputing in a field of the form and use that value.

This is what my model looks like

```
class Deposit < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :credit_card
  belongs_to  :user

  validates   :credit_card,          presence: true
  validates   :user,                 presence: true
  validates   :tx_type,              inclusion: %w(debit credit)
  # validates   :amount,               presence: true, numericality: true

  before_create :add_transaction_to_merchant
  after_create  :update_user_balance
  attr_readonly :credit_card_id, :user_id, :fee_id, :tx_type, :status, :merchant_tx_id

  attr_accessible :tx_type, :amount, :status, :merchant_tx_id, :credit_card_id,
                  :user_id, :user

  def amount
    return attributes[:amount] if attributes[:amount]
    set_amount
  end

  def tx_type
    attributes[:tx_type] || 'debit'
  end

  def send_receipt
    Resque.enqueue(PaymentCompletedSender, self.id)
  end

  def update_user_balance
    user_balance =user.balance + set_amount
    user.balance = user_balance
    user.save
  end

  private

  def add_transaction_to_merchant
    set_amount
    return false if credit_card.nil?
    return true unless amount > 0
    result = Braintree::Transaction.sale(
      amount: amount,
      payment_method_token: credit_card.token,
      options: { submit_for_settlement: true }
    )

    if result.success?
      self.merchant_tx_id = result.transaction.id
      # status will be authorized or submitted_for_settlement
      self.status = result.transaction.status
    else
      errors.add(:base, result.message)
      if result.transaction.nil?
        # validation errors prevented transaction from being created
        logger.error(result.errors)
      else
        self.merchant_tx_id = result.transaction.id
        # status will be processor_declined, gateway_rejected, or failed
        self.status = result.transaction.status
      end
    end
  end

  def set_amount
    attributes[:amount]
  end

end
```

The Controller:

```
# POST /deposits
  # POST /deposits.json
  def create
    @deposit = Deposit.new(params[:deposit])
    @deposit.user = current_user
    @deposit.credit_card = current_user.credit_cards.try(:first)

    binding.pry
    respond_to do |format|
      if @deposit.save
        format.html { redirect_to "/", notice: 'Deposit was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @deposit, status: :created, location: @deposit }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @deposit.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

This is what is params the form is sending

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"r0M0sRr7QO9kl0IWrJSgvj45DFrC6mbbuA+ttgEaUI0=",
 "deposit"=>{"amount"=>"100"},
 "commit"=>"Pay Now"}
```

Any thoughts on how to return the value of amount from the form in the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are doing this right? `@deposit = Deposit.new(params[:deposit])` if you remove the `amount` and `set_amount` method in the model, you should be able to just use `amount` or `self.amount` in the model so the following should be enough

```
def add_transaction_to_merchant
  return false if credit_card.nil?
  return true unless amount > 0

  result = Braintree::Transaction.sale(
    amount: amount,
    payment_method_token: credit_card.token,
    options: { submit_for_settlement: true }
  )
```

Comment: Awesome! That worked. I'm working off someone else's code to modify payment processing. Thanks!